# Entity Framework and database support

Tags: entity-framework

we know that we can generate EDMX model from sql server because EF support sql server. if my database is Oracle,MS-access or MySql then it supports or not. does it support ODBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF is database independent but it requires EF ADO.NET provider to be supplied for the database. You can check [the list of databases offering such provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx). MS-Access is not among them.

The independence is little bit more theoretical because if you are using EDMX it has always its SSDL part bounded to single provider. If you want to support more databases you must have separate SSDL or whole EDMX for each provider. This is not the problem with EFv4.1 and code-first approach.